# Default Display of Colors on Bar Chart in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an issue with Matplotlib that I can't quite figure out.

If I make a bar chart like so:

```
df['Embarked'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh');
```

I get this chart as a result:

[image]

Notice the different colors of each bar.

Apparently for some of my co-workers, they get different appearances than mine and I'm not sure why it's the case.

In their case, the bar colors are mono-chromatic.

Now, on my chart, I can modify bar colors in the following way:

```
df['Embarked'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh', color=['red', 'green', 'blue']);
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

However, the same people who have monochromatic bar charts also can't use multiple colors in the `color` argument to any effect.

Two questions:

1).  What is causing this basic discrepancy in appearance?

2).  For people who have the one-color default, how do they modify the colors of their bar chart?

Thank you.

Comment: 1) Compare the pandas version in use. Theirs might be newer than yours.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - mine is `0.23.4`

Comment: 2) I cannot reproduce this. The `color=['red', 'green', 'blue']` should work as expected, and it does for me on `0.24.2`.